# active reports in C /CLI

Tags: c++-cli, activereports

Can we use Active Reports 7.0 in C++/CLI? I have just started using active reports. I tried building a report in C# without any problem. I tried doing the same in C++/CLI, but I am unable to use the Active reports toolbox. And also when running the application, it is giving licensing errors.

Comment: If you get licensing errors, asking ComponentOne might be the better option than asking some random guy on the internet.

Comment: @nvoigt Yes, I have asked them and they are yet to respond. In the meanwhile, in the first place, is it possible to create an active report using C++/CLI? Because, I have seen that the Active Report specific toolbar items are greyed out in C++/CLI whereas in C# they are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The designer that generates code-based won't work with C++/CLI. You also won't be able to write "script" inside the reports with C++. However, you can design reports as the [XML-based reports (rpx)](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/?arWLKBasicXMLReports.html) instead and then you shouldn't have any problem instantiating and calling on those from C++ via the [SectionReport](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/?GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v7~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport.html) class (for example). Something like the following:

```
GrapeCity::ActiveReports::SectionReport ^sectionReport = gcnew GrapeCity::ActiveReports::SectionReport();
System::Xml::XmlTextReader ^xtr = new System::Xml::XmlTextReader("..\\..\\rptScript.rpx");
sectionReport->LoadLayout(xtr);
xtr->Close();
viewer1->LoadDocument(sectionReport);
...
```

Keep in mind ActiveReports users are almost exclusively C# & VB.NET users so you won't find any C++ code samples, but it should be pretty trivial to translate the code from C# to C++/CLI.

The example is based on SectionReport not [PageReport](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/?GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v7~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.PageReport.html), but PageReport is entirely xml-based so it should work easily too.

So to clarify, if you want a C++ only solution, you need to do the following:

Create your reports as XML-based reports (*.rpx files) using the "Standalone" designer application that is installed in the start menu when you install ActiveReports. Since you can save your reports as a standalone, independent .rpx file, you **will not need to use any C#/VB.NET DLL**. As shown in the code example above, you can just load the .rpx files from a file directly from C++ (for example).

Although **this technique does not require any C# or VB.NET DLL/EXE**, if you use the scripting feature inside the standalone .rpx report file, the script will have to be either C# or VB script. However, you won't have to compile that yourself, ActiveReports deals with the script internally.

Comment: hello Scott.
I was planning to directly work in c++/cli without using any c# dll (even for Active Reports).Since C++/CLI is a managed envment, I assumed that I can create AR in C++/CLI too.
Could you please clarify my foll doubts?   
1) Is it possible to create AR in C++/CLI without depending on anything in C#? 
2) If I am forced to create these reports in a c# dll before using it in C++/CLI, then can't I directly call the code generated report in C++/CLI? Or could only an xml based report created in c# be called in C+++/CLI as you suggested?
Sorry for pestering you with these doubts. Thanks.

Comment: @Charan I added a clarification above to answer your questions. Short answer is "yes, you can create reports without compiling a C# DLL."

Comment: Excellent! it worked. However, if I want to have interaction between my C++/CLI data and the Active Report, I can't have it directly. Am I right? I mean, if there is a textbox in the report which I want to associate with a wrapped data in my C++/CLI application, I can't link the textbox with my C++ data.

Comment: @Charan Regarding "wrapped data": I'll probably need more information. Maybe you should consider it another question? You could create an IList data source or publish data to the report via an System.Data.IDataReader implementation written in C++/CLI since AR can bind to either of these types of data, but that's all I can think of (see IEnumerable and Unbound at http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/?BindReportstoaDataSource.html ).

Comment: @scott Could you please elaborate on IDataReader implementation in c++/cli? Regarding the interaction between xml based report and C++/CLI, I have posted it as a different question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892875/c-cli-xml-based-active-reports>. I guess it is not possible but would like to know your take on it.