# C++/CLI - XML based active reports

Tags: c++-cli, activereports

This is in continuation to one of my previous queries([active reports in C /CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583240/active-reports-in-c-cli)). I am accessing an xml-based active report from a C++/CLI application. Is there any way by which I can have a data communication with the active report from C++/CLI, for example, I want to print the managed data present in the C++/CLI application on the details section of the XML report which the application accesses. I don't want to use any c# code. Can it be done? Thanks.

Comment: You are going to have to find a report generator that supports binding to C++/CLI.  That's going to be a long and likely to be fruitless effort, no component vendor thinks that supporting this makes sense when language interop in .NET works so well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, ActiveReports can do it. Since C++/CLI produces standard .NET objects you can create objects in C++/CLI and ActiveReports will bind to them. Create an IEnumerable collection of objects that you want to bind to (each object in the collection is like a database "row").

Take a look at the examples at [Binding Reports to a Data Source](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/webframe.html?arHOWBindReportstoaDataSource.html). Expand the code sections under the heading *To use the IEnumerable data source* and you'll see how to do it in C#. You would do precisely the same thing in C++/CLI, you'll just change the syntax from C# to C++/CLI. Clearly, you know C++/CLI syntax so you can do that part, but I think this answers your question regarding how to do this with ActiveReports.

**Update based on question asked in comments:**

You should be able to handle an ActiveReports' event such as the [FetchData event](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/webframe.html?ActiveReports6~DataDynamics.ActiveReports.ActiveReport~FetchData_EV.html) using something like the following code:

```
void MyFetchDataHandler(Object^ sender, FetchEventArgs^ eArgs) 
{
 //put handling code here...
}

myReport->FetchData += ref new FetchEventHandler(this, &MyClass::MyFetchDataHandler)
```

I didn't compile this (I don't have AR handy), but it should be close. Please see [Microsoft's reference documentation on C++/CLI event syntax here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755799.aspx).

Comment: @Scott I've looked at the example and tried to create a simple similar example in C. ++/CLI. But how do we access the DataInitialise and FetchData functions of the report in C++/CLI? Thanks.

Comment: I added more detail to the answer.